# you would know from experience

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Does **"you would know from experience"** in the following dialogue mean "so, your experience tells that"?

Context:

American: Coffee for me.

Turk: Tea if you please.

American: I should think you'd prefer...

Turk: Pardon me for saying, sir... we do so many things well here in America, 
but coffee is not one of them.

American: Ha! Well, you would know from experience.

Comment: No way an American said "I *should think* that...". I call baloney, this happened in London ;) Anyway, yes, he's saying the other guy, being a Turk, should know his coffee (Turks, stereotypically, adoring coffee).

Comment: But why does the Turk say, “We”?

Comment: @Jim I'm curious as well. hopefully OP would name the source of this dialogue

Comment: @Chris Gong Here is the source: http://www.clockwork-comics.com/2011/08/04/tea-please/

Comment: @user127733 Ha! British! I knew it. Vindication!

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering where this excerpt came from because the only thing I can think of is that the dialogue refers to the history and origins of coffee. According to the [USA National Coffee Association](http://www.ncausa.org/About-Coffee/History-of-Coffee), coffee was invented by a goat herder named Kaldi in Yemen. At the time of the discovery, 15th century, Yemen was part the Ottoman Empire, which was primarily of Turkish ethnicity.

The American in the dialogue is taking a subtle jab at the Turk's ethnicity in the sense that the Turk would know coffee better from experience because of his culture. Basically, the American is insinuating that the Turk, due to his identity, should know what good coffee is. And perhaps rightfully so! In addition to the fact that modern coffee brewing styles are based on the original Turkish process, Turkish coffee is famous for having the foamy top and coffee ground bottom that give it that fine, grinded coffee bean taste.

[image]

Interesting sources:

http://www.turkishstylegroundcoffee.com/turkish-style-coffee/

http://thesavorycafened.com/drinking-it-the-turkish-way-how-to-drink-turkish-coffee/

https://www.walksofturkey.com/blog/turkish-food/how-to-drink-turkish-coffee-making-and-enjoying-turkeys-most-iconic-brew